# Python zpl laberaly

Tags: python, print, zebra, zpl

Estoy usando Laberaly ZPL Web Service, http://labelary.com/service.html#python
En la documentación menciona que con pdf se puede generar hasta 50 labels. cómo indicaría en el parámetro files del response suponiendo que quiero generar 2 etiquetas una que diga hello world 1 hello world 2

```
import requests
import shutil

zpl = '^xa^cfa,50^fo100,100^fdHello World^fs^xz'

# adjust print density (8dpmm), label width (4 inches), label height (6 inches), and label index (0) as necessary
url = 'http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/'
files = {'file' : zpl}
headers = {'Accept' : 'application/pdf'} # omit this line to get PNG images back
response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, files = files, stream = True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    with open('label.pdf', 'wb') as out_file: # change file name for PNG images
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
else:
    print('Error: ' + response.text)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví, la variable zpl debe verse así

```
zpl = '^xa^cfa,50^fo100,100^fdHello World^fs^xz^xa^cfa,50^fo100,100^fdHello World^fs^xz'
```

Esto imprimiría 2 etiquetas